# NLTK não possui uma gramática de português universal para parsing

Tags: python, parser, nltk

Estou há alguns dias procurando uma gramática para criar parsing trees no NLTK, mas ao contrário da língua inglesa, os exemplos que encontro exigem que sejam criadas gramáticas para representação de constituintes sintáticos da frase, por exemplo:

VP -> Det V

Exemplo no NLTK

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}"
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
```

1. Existe alguma gramática para português já pronta ou genérica? Caso não, existe alguma técnica que supere a criação manual de cada um destes padrões gramaticais?
2. Existe um modo de reproduzir este mesmo processo no Spacy?